# How to fetch record with single occurrence multiple times using IN statement in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having one master table **ItemMaster**. It contains all unique records. I'm having another **ItemOrder** table where items have multiple occurrences. Now I want to fetch the same item as many times I call it in **IN** statement (the item ids are auto-generated by code).

Example -

**ItemMaster Columns** - ItemId, ItemCode, ItemName, Description, etc...

**ItemOrder Columns** - ItemId, ItemFinish, etc...

I'm using -

```
SELECT ItemId, ItemCode FROM ItemMaster WHERE ItemId IN (10, 20, 30, 40, 10, 50, 20,...);
```

I want that the result-set should contain Item # 10 OR 20 twice. This IN statement is being auto-generated. Items are same but differ based on their finishing!

Will appreciate. Thanks!

...

Comment: Do a JOIN instead of IN.

Comment: Could you please guide or give code?

Comment: You can't JUST by using in; that's just now how "In" works..  In simply returns all values IN the list regardless of how many times it occurs.  Lets say your data has 7 "20"'s in it.  Which 2 of the 7 "20's" would you want?   Cross apply and top could be used to limit all records returned for each item to be no greater than the max;  a cursor could be used to parse each one individually and loop though each value instead of using In.  But to my knowledge you can't limit records returned to the number of occurrences of a value in the In statement.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Please visit http://anchulgupta.com/sql.PNG . The result-set is showing single occurrences of say 45 whereas I want it should come twice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `join`:

```
SELECT v.ItemId, m.ItemCode
FROM (VALUES (10), (20), (30), (40), (20), . . .
     ) v(ItemId) JOIN
     ItemMaster im
     ON im.ItemId = v.ItemId;
```

Note:  If you want to keep non-matching `itemids` as well, then use `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something: but I think he's after limiting the data to return Item ID "20" only twice from ItemOrder (among other values in the in).  I don't see `itemOrder` here at all.  and just twice even if it has 5 occurrences of "20"  since the `In` statement only has 20 listed twice.   Had me intrigued though I thought I was learning something new; and maybe I still am going to! :P~~

Comment: The ItemOrder table has multiple orders of different customers. A customer can order same item twice or thrice, etc. based on different Finishing Colors. So, that's the scenario. You can suggest any other query as well. I just have a series of ItemId returned from the code.